# Is there any difference between “I have interest” and “I have interested”?

Tags: grammar, tense

If I say I  have interest in music  OR I have interested in music, Is there any difference in meaning of both?

Comment: You should first search on such phrases (have interest/have interested) for actual usage, which may answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Neither expression is good English. "I have interested in music" is just not English at all. In that context, 'interested' requires an object, as in "I have interested my young son in music." 
You could say "I have **an** interest in music". That would imply that amongst the numerous pursuits that interest you, one of them is music. Although that could be said, I doubt that it ever would be in such a general form. That formulation works in answer to a question such as "Are you interested in music?". Answer "I have an interest in early Dutch organ music."

What I think you mean would normally be expressed in English as "I am interested in music".